# Getting localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//logs’: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop2

I have a complete new hadoop 2.9 setup installed, and everything seems to be fine. However, There is just one error that I am not able to get through. When I execute the command

start-dfs.sh

I get below errors:

```
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access '//logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to //logs/hadoop-amitesh-namenode-amitesh-VirtualBox.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: //logs/hadoop-amitesh-namenode-amitesh-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open '//logs/hadoop-amitesh-namenode-amitesh-VirtualBox.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: //logs/hadoop-amitesh-namenode-amitesh-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: //logs/hadoop-amitesh-namenode-amitesh-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
```

There are 2 observations:

```
1)The error says //logs. However, ideally the path should had been /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.0. Not sure about it

2) By being sudo, I gave chown -R amitesh:amitesh hadoop.
  However, the top 2 directories "usr" and "local" still has root ownership:group.
```

Any suggestions? I did see some other article on stackoverflow, but they were not helpful to my case.

Comment: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘//logs’: Permission denied` Because the usr directory does not have write permission either you run the command as sudo start-dfs.sh or sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /usr

Comment: @Amit, as per your suggestion I ran sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /usr , now the permission is 777, but the owership and group ownership is still with root. I tried changiing that, but its not happening

Comment: This should have probably worked.. try doing through super user.

Comment: I think it is trying to make `$HADOOP_HOME/logs`... Did you empty out that variable? If not, you can look at `sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159` to see what variables are being used

Comment: I got a work around done. I had created the log dir manually inside the hadoop home dir, and set the variable inside /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh under $HADOOP_HOME/logs. Issue resolved.